# What kind of server can we connect to from iPhone Files app?

Tags: iphone, network, file-sharing, files.app

If I remember correctly, in the past I was able to connect to smb and/or webdav servers from the iPhone Files app. I tried to connect to my webdav server today but it now doesn't work.

It actually creates the connection, but I cannot navigate and show the files.

[image]

What kind of server can we connect to from iPhone Files app?